# What make a Corda X500 name unique?

Tags: corda

According to the Corda Network documentation https://corda.network/participation/distinguishedname/

> A X.500 must be unique within Corda Network. The combination of O and OU are used for the uniqueness check, and the other fields are considered as attributes of the identity.

Is this uniqueness check specific to the Corda Network or does it also apply to private Corda Networks? Within the Corda Network is it unique across all zones?

If not then what are the X500 name uniqueness checks for X500 names of:

1. CENM networks
2. Bootstrapped networks

Answer (score 0):

The uniqueness check is enforced on any network, including the Corda Network (tCN) and any other private Corda Networks. And it needs to be unique across all zones.

That is, the X500 names need to be unique across zones regardless of deploying on the tCN or any private network (using CENM or bootstrapper).

The reason is that the same identity manager is used for all zones across the network and the uniqueness is checked on the identity manager level. Also, A bit future thinking on the network, clients might consider subzone merging / cross-zone interop, and etc. So this grants them the flexibility and ability to achieve that in the future.

To further address your questions: How would you enforce uniquessness checks on bootstrap network and CECM networks?
The CENM Identity Operator will have built-in checking to enforce the uniqueness check. With newtwork boostrapper, there is no uniqueness check, so use it with caution.